# Execute href and Open URL in a new window

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have postback method in asp.net and after that I want to open new blank page.

I am displaying some message from client side and explicitly clicking a href but that href is not firing.

```
<a href="../tools/pagename.aspx" target="_blank" id="aProcess"></a>

function DownloadData()
{
   $("#aProcess").click();
}
```

I want to execute href in new page.
window.open() which I do not want to use. I want to open new window. using window.open() as it may blocked by browser sometime. Therefore a href call explicitly I want to trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this if you want the url to be opened in the current window

```
document.location.href = 'http://url.com';
```

If you want the url opened in a new window without using `window.open()`. You can use

```
window.showModalDialog("http://url.com",window);
```

Comment: Yea, but it will open in same window. I want to open new window. Also do not want to use window.open() as it may blocked.

Comment: I already have popup opened and window.open nor showModaldialog working.

Comment: `Window.open` should work on all browsers without problems as long as you are firing it manually ie: button click. But if you run `window.open` in an event that the user has no control over, it will be considered as a popup and will be blocked. So, I really recommend that you explain more about what you are trying to do instead of saying "I don't want to use window.open".

Comment: Thanks for your help..Yes, you are right. I already have popup opened in IE, I am opening window.open - which can be blocked. So I want to open up new page which sets in href.

Comment: [window.showModalDialog is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Answer (score 1):

In order to open a new browser window with jquery you can use window.open() method:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

`URL:` Optional. Specifies the URL of the page to open. If no URL is specified, a new window with about:blank is opened.

`name:`Optional.Specifies the target attribute or the name of the window.

`specs:`Optional. A comma-separated list of items.

`replace:`Optional.Specifies whether the URL creates a new entry or replaces the current entry in the history list(`true||false`).

to open your page:

```
$("a#aProcess").click(function(){
    window.open('http://localhost:port/...','_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for change current page url:

```
function DownloadData()
{
   window.location = 'new url';
}
```

for opening new page:

```
window.open(url);
```

This is the only thing you can do if browser settings permit it.

Fortunately!

If it was different i think that will be impossible to surf the web without having tons of popup opened

Comment: Yea, but it will open in same window. I want to open new window. Also do not want to use window.open() as it may blocked.

Comment: @Keyur then the problem is somewhere else in your code and not related to that function

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("a#aProcess").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
    });
```